# Double summation giving unexpected result

Tags: warning-messages, summation

The expression (in a notebook with Wolfram Mathematica 12.0.0)

```
Sum[s[i, j] - s[j, i], {j, b}, {i, b}]
```

Produces the result

> 1/2 b EulerPhi[b]

Can anyone explain this?  Some forgotten prank hidden in the kernel's built-in rules?

Edit: `Sum[i - j, {i, k}, {j, k}]` does the same; any variable names can be used.

Comment: Run `ClearAll[s]` and try again.

Comment: I swear I shut down the entire program and restarted it, with the same result.  However, the gremlin has gone.  (It was doing the same for the difference of any expression with two variables swapped.)  I'll have to assume I had created some substitution rule that somehow did not clear.

Comment: It's back.  I rebooted my computer, started Mathematica, and that was the first thing I entered into a fresh notebook.  Same result.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce any of your results.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Weird.  Mathematica and I just do not get on.

Comment: Strange, I can reproduce locally and on [Wolfram Cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/3c348365-0231-46f6-a7be-9e6c04601d87)

Comment: Ah, so I'm not losing my marbles ... thanks for confirming.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with v12.0.0 with macOS 10.14.6

Comment: MMA v11.0.1: `Sum[s[i, j] - s[j, i], {j, b}, {i, b}] (*0*)`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, interesting.  I wonder whether that is the result of some deeper insight on a symmetric sum on an alternating expression that I'd expect might be in `Simplify` (which is not being invoked here), or a manifestation of a bug.

Comment: Obviously the matrix `s[i, j] - s[j, i]` is skew symmetric, sum over all coefficients must be zero !

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by "a symmetric sum on an alternating [i.e. skew symmetric] expression".  However, Mathematica does not generally apply simple rules such as distributivity without explicit invocation of `Expand` or `Simplify`.  This might be enthusiastic simplification for v11, but v12 clearly gets it wrong.

Comment: macos 10.14.5 mma 12, i also get this result...

Comment: MMA v12.1: (* 0 *)

Comment: Yeah, I was told by Wolfram that this would be fixed in the next version after I gave it as an example from the list of problems that I have experienced from Mathematica, but since I am not their QA, I have not bothered to give them a list.  Considering the large number of in-your-face problems that I have experienced (including, for example, the broken "undo" editing feature), I have elected to terminate the licence subscription.